# How do you pass an array in C# using Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor-pages

This is my viewtrainees.cshtml.cs file snippets that contain the array code:

```
public class viewTraineeModel : PageModel
{
    public string[] traineeinfo { get; set; }
    (...)
```

In my OnGet():

```
string[] traineeinfo = new string[Convert.ToInt32(countnum)];

int i = 0;

while (trainees.Read())
{
    traineeinfo[i] = trainees["t3_win"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

So everything is set in my array fine, I even tested it within the .cs file. However, when I pass the array or think I pass the array to the view it ALWAYS gives me an internal error.

I have tried on my viewtrainees.cshtml file:

```
@Model.traineeinfo[0]
```

And I get NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error.

The head element of my code looks like this.

```
@page
@model T3_Landing.Pages.viewTraineeModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "View Trainees";

    string[] traineeinfo = Model.traineeinfo as string[];    
}
```

I have tried it with and without re-initializing the string array as seen above. I really want this to work.

Just a note I can pass regular strings just fine using @Model.examplestring but never an array, list, or object.

Comment: why don't you pass the comma separated string instead of array

Comment: @Roshan why do that at all? Arrays work just fine in Razor. If they didn't all the table and list rendering examples (ie all of them) would fail. The Razor Page runs on the *server* and produces HTML. There's no reason to encode data between model and page. The page's data *is* the model

Comment: What's the error and what do you mean `when I pass the array or think I pass the array to the view it`? The page *has* the model, you don't pass it to the page. ` Model.traineeinfo` is a `string[]`, it doesn't need casting. *Did* you initialize that property though, or is it left `null`? Does it contain anything? Your code could throw an NRE if `traineeinfo` isn't initialized, or if there are no items in the array

Comment: `string[] traineeinfo = new string[Convert.ToInt32(countnum)];` creates a local variable, it doesn't set the property. I bet there's a compiler or analyzer warning about this, and another one about naming convention violations for the `traineeeinfo` property name. Property names and public methods should use Pascal-case.  Those are part of the class/model's API. Fields, variables are lower or camel-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without the full context, but it looks like you're *hiding* the class member by declaring a local variable within `OnGet()`:

```
string[] traineeinfo = new string[Convert.ToInt32(countnum)];
```

This creates a *local* variable named `traineeinfo` that hides the class property (if that's the case I would expect a compiler warning). Since the class property is not set, you get a null reference exception in your Razor page.

Try just

```
traineeinfo = new string[Convert.ToInt32(countnum)];
```

I would also recommend using camel case to make it easier to read:

```
public string[] TraineeInfo { get; set; }

....

TraineeInfo = new string[Convert.ToInt32(countnum)];
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `TraineeInfo =` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Good catch. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here on constructor, I think you may initialize string array for prevent null value.

```cs
public class viewTraineeModel : PageModel
{
public string[] traineeinfo { get; set; }
...

public viewTraineeModel()
{
traineeinfo=new string[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please drop a screen shot or code snippet of how you're passing the data to your view from your controller method end. That will determine if you have the data you want to work with in your view in the first place.